# Cookie.ExpireTimeSpan ignored and set to Session in CookieAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cookie-authentication

I'm having an issue while trying to set the **expire** time of a cookie in my `CookieAuthentication`, it seems that `ExpireTimeSpan` is just ignored and when i get the cookie in the browser it's expire time is set to `Session`..

I'm using c# 8.0 w/ .NET Core 3.1 and here is my `ConfigureService` code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie.Name = "authToken";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://example.com/test/expired.html");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

But that's how i get it

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);` instructs how long authentication ticket itself is valid.

> Controls how much time the authentication ticket stored in the cookie
>   will remain valid from the point it is created The expiration
>   information is stored in the protected cookie ticket. Because of that
>   an expired cookie will be ignored even if it is passed to the server
>   after the browser should have purged it.
>
> This is separate from the value of , which specifies how long the
>   browser will keep the cookie.
>
> [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.expiretimespan?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationOptions_ExpireTimeSpan)

You want to control cookie expiration using `Expiration` property on `Cookie` property.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => {
        options.Cookie.Name = "authToken";
        /// control cookie expiration
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://example.com/test/expired.html");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Alternatively, you can set `MaxAge` property too.

Comment: in .NET Core 3.1 `Cookie.Expiration` seems to be obsolete, when i try to set it i just get `OptionsValidationException: Cookie.Expiration is ignored, use ExpireTimeSpan instead.`

Comment: But damn yea MaxAge was the right one to set, thank you mate

Answer (score 4):

For my new ASP.NET MVC 6 project `ExpireTimeSpan` doesn't work, but `MaxAge` works well.

```
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{      
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an application in .net core 3.1 my ConfigureServices looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    //options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder() { Name = "EcomAuth" };
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
});
```

for some bug, when I set the cookie name the code stops working, so this line is commented out. This is my login action

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name, ClaimValueTypes.String),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userType.Name, ClaimValueTypes.String),
    new Claim("Idusuario",user.IdUser.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String),
};

ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    AllowRefresh = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
    IsPersistent = true,
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44318/Account/Logout"
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), authProperties);
```

its working fine to me.

Comment: Even by removing cookie name and by adding ExpiresUtc when the cookie is created nothing changed and the expire time is still set to Session..